# Chart.js - Mixed Chart: Bar Graph with Diagonal Line

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using Chart.js, trying to display a diagonal line (representing goal) over a bar graph (representing actual.  I would like the actuals line to overlay the bar graph.

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
window[id] = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Actual',
            data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
          
        }, {
            label: 'Goal',
                data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            fill:false,

            // Changes this dataset to become a line
           type: 'line',
           backgroundColor: "red",
           borderColor:"red"
        }],
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April']},
    
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
       
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

But my chart comes out looking like this:
[image]

I've tried changing the order using the order: parameter for the bar and line but it did not change the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
The way I got this to work was to have the line elements first in the dataset.

Adding order:1 and order:2 to the bar/line datasets did not affect the display.